# How are the values 4.5 and 1.5 determined in this square?

Tags: geometry

How are the values 4.5 and 1.5 determined?

[image]

The clue supposes to be in here:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? No idea what the problem is that you are solving

Comment: @user44197 trying to figure out how the values 4.5 and 1.5 are determined. It is in the title

Comment: What is the problem? You don't specify where $H'$ is! From the solution and the image of the pyramid, I can determine that it is the projection of $H$ on the ground-level. So, what is the problem? Is it to see why $H'$ is the middle of $DM$? Or is it to come up with the sides 1.5 and 4.5? (Of what? Again from the image and the solution, we can infer that the triangle formed by $A$, $H'$ and the unnamed point is a right triangle, but that's something you should really state! In fact, realizing this is nearly all of the solution.)

Answer (score 1):

Letting $P$ be the intersection point of $AD$ and its perpendicular line which passes through $H^\prime$.

Since we can see $DH^\prime : H^\prime B=1:3$ (this is because $DH^\prime : H^\prime M=1:1$), we have
$$PH^\prime : AB=1:4\iff PH^\prime:6=1:4.$$
Hence, we have
$$PH^\prime=6/4=1.5.$$
Also, since $DP:PA=1:3,$
$$PA=DA\times (3/4)=6\times (3/4)=4.5.$$
Does this help?

Comment: How do you know that DH′:H′M=1:1?

Comment: Since $TN:NM=1:1$, $TH : HD=1:1.$ So, $DH^\prime : H^\prime M=1:1.$

Comment: Did you get it? Two triangles $THN,TDM$ are similar, and two triangles $TDM, HDH^\prime$ are similar too.

Comment: @WardWalter: Does this help? If not, why not ask?